# Wildcard route for static content in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular7-router

I am learning Angular 7 by studying [this example app](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app).  The example app uses a wildcard route to handle all otherwise-unhandled routes.

Specifically, this [app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts) directs all miscellaneous routes to [AppConfig.routes.error404](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/configs/app.config.ts), which is handled by [Error404PageComponent.ts](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/shared/pages/error404-page/error404-page.component.ts), which then ultimately serves up [error404-page.component.html](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/shared/pages/error404-page/error404-page.component.html) for every possible route that is not specified by its own component and named route.

> **What specific changes would need to be made to the code in this sample app in order for the wildcard route serve different static content for different submitted routes?**

For example, if a web user typed in the route `/i-am-a-jelly-donut`, what changes would need to be made so that the request would 1.) continue to go through `Error404PageComponent.ts`, but have the user's browser receive a new `i-am-a-jelly-donut.page.html` instead of the `error404-page.component.html` view?

> **The `Error404PageComponent.ts` would still serve up `error404-page.component.html` for every non-specified route.  However, we would be adding logic to give special handling inside `Error404PageComponent` for a specific static route in addition to the logic for every non-specified route.**

The goal here is to be able to handle static routes without having to create a separate component for each and every route.  Think, for example, of a blog where most of the routes have an identical template, but with different content in each blog entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are compiled into the components at build time and you are not going to be able to change which template a component uses at runtime but you can hide and show sections based on conditions. Inject the router into your component

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Now you can set a variable on your component based on if the route contains 'i-am-a-jelly-donut'

```
jellyDonut = this.router.url.indexOf('i-am-a-jelly-donut') !== -1;
```

and in your template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="jellyDonut">
  Jelly Donut
</ngcontainer>

<ng-container *ngIf="!jellyDonut">
  Other stuff
</ngcontainer>
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for answering the OP on the level on which it was asked.  Are you willing to add a comment to direct this specific follow up?  ...  I am concerned that this might not scale if for example the site grows to several hundred of these identically-formatted "blog entries", each needing their own route, but none of which warrant their own components.  What should I research to identify approaches to this problem for higher numbers of routes?

Comment: Then use a route paramater, not a catch all

Comment: { path: ':blogId', component: BlogComponent }

Comment: Blog component can load the content that is for blogId

Comment: The use case would be blog entries which each need their own fully specified routes for search engines.  From your brief 2 sentences, I see the same issue of hundreds of route options inside BlogComponent.  Can you elaborate at least enough for me to understand what your suggestion would look like so I can understand how it would address the requirement?

Comment: Where do you plan on saving the blog entries? Normally you would have the content saved in a database and then load the content based on the blog id, you would have have hundreds of blog entries hardcoded on a single template.

Comment: There are lots of CRUD examples that load data based on ID.  But a unique and descriptive URL for each entry is better for many reasons, including search engines.  Also, exposing each record's ID in the url used to be frowned upon for security reasons.  ...  Here, I imagined this scaling to rely on a JSON file for each blog entry, perhaps with fields for route, body html, etc. ...  I do not want to make this question too complicated.  I am just asking for direction for my independent research.

Comment: The blog id can be i-am-a-jelly-donut